# wordpress url rewrite to add username

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite the url of my wordpress site in following format:

FROM : `http://localhost/wp351/?user=arvind`

TO: `http://localhost/wp351/arvind`

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: rewriting for authors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this:

```
add_action('init','url_init');
function url_init() {
    global $wp, $wp_rewrite;
    $wp->add_query_var('user');

    //Rewrite abc.com/me/user=arvind to abc.com/me/arvind
    //$wp_rewrite->add_rule('me/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?pagename=me&user=$matches[1]', 'top');

    //Rewrite abc.com/user=arvind to abc.comm/arvind
    $wp_rewrite->add_rule('([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?user=$matches[1]', 'top');

    // Once you get working, remove this next line
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(false);
}
```